# Unable to access checkbox on new form using Python and Chromedriver

Tags: python, forms, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to check a box that is displayed on a new form from a website.

[Form popup looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlYsB.png)

My code is as follows:

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id('btnworksheetAdd')
inputElement.click()

#Switch to new window
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id('chkFilterTNumbers')

inputElement.click()
```

Here's the error I get:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"chkFilterTNumbers"}
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

[Here's the element description:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FpZA.png)

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: The switch_to_window() is smelly - are you sure your popup is in a new browser?  After that, I'd look to see if it is a timing issue where it is taking longer to show than it is taking the selenium code to run.  Meaning:  add a wait for the element to exist.

Comment: Thanks, OCary. Added a delay and everything worked fine.